# Cleaning up tweets before sentiment analysis on cryptocurrencies

Tags: python, twitter, analysis, cryptocurrency

I am trying to analyse twitter sentiment and right now I have a code which scrapes tweets from twitter with API and puts them in an excel file followed by their sentiment score, however I want to try and clean these tweets before they are put into the excel file and before they are analysed through the google cloud NLP.

**below is the code that scrapes the tweets**

```
    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
    if(maxId <= 0):
            newTweets = api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, count=tweetsPerQry, lang="en",
    result_type="recent", tweet_mode="extended")
    else:
                newTweets =  api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, count=tweetsPerQry, lang="en",
    max_id=str(maxId -1), result_type="recent", tweet_mode="extended")

    if not newTweets:
            print("Tweet habis")
            break

    for tweet in newTweets:
            d={}
            d["text"] = tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')
            print (d["text"])
            listposts.append(d)

    tweetCount += len(newTweets)
    maxId = newTweets[-1].id
    print (listposts)
```

**and below is the code that cleans tweets**

```
def clean_tweet(tweet):
if type(tweet) == np.float:
    return ""
temp = tweet.lower()
temp = re.sub("'", "", temp) # to avoid removing contractions in english
temp = re.sub("@[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
temp = re.sub("#[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
temp = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', temp)
temp = re.sub('[()!?]', ' ', temp)
temp = re.sub('\[.*?\]',' ', temp)
temp = re.sub("[^a-z0-9]"," ", temp)
temp = temp.split()
temp = [w for w in temp if not w in stopwords]
temp = " ".join(word for word in temp)
return temp

tweets = [""]

results = [clean_tweet(tw) for tw in tweets]
results
```

somehow I want to combine these two pieces of code so that the tweets go into the clean_tweet function before being put into the excel file and thus also being analysed on sentiment.

Comment: Are you asking how to write them to an excel file? Or how to call your `clean_tweet` function from your scraping code?

Comment: how to call my clean_tweet function from scraping the code

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following function to clean tweets (this is just your function with indentation fixed):

```py
def clean_tweet(tweet):
    if type(tweet) == np.float:
        return ""
    temp = tweet.lower()
    temp = re.sub("'", "", temp) # to avoid removing contractions in english
    temp = re.sub("@[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
    temp = re.sub("#[A-Za-z0-9_]+","", temp)
    temp = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', temp)
    temp = re.sub('[()!?]', ' ', temp)
    temp = re.sub('\[.*?\]',' ', temp)
    temp = re.sub("[^a-z0-9]"," ", temp)
    temp = temp.split()
    temp = [w for w in temp if not w in stopwords]
    temp = " ".join(word for word in temp)
    return temp
```

Your other block of code has some problems that I'm not fixing here; for example, `listposts` is never defined, before you try to append to it. You also might have some indentation issues. With that in mind, you can call the function as follows:

```py
tweetCount = 0

while tweetCount < maxTweets:
    if(maxId <= 0):
            newTweets = api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, count=tweetsPerQry, lang="en",
    result_type="recent", tweet_mode="extended")
    else:
            newTweets =  api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, count=tweetsPerQry, lang="en",
    max_id=str(maxId -1), result_type="recent", tweet_mode="extended")

    if not newTweets:
            print("Tweet habis")
            break

    for tweet in newTweets:
            print("Tweet before cleaning:", tweet, sep="\n")
            tweet = clean_tweet(tweet)
            print("Tweet after cleaning:", tweet, sep="\n")
            listposts.append(d)

    tweetCount += len(newTweets)
    maxId = newTweets[-1].id
    # Instead of just printing listposts, this is where I would
    # write each entry of it to a line in a csv file
```